# Pronouncing initials as a word

Tags: names, nicknames

I have long 3 names that i want to shorten so people can pronounce it easier, the initials of my full name are "M.E.Z", which sound a little heavy to pronounce letter by letter, do name initials have to be pronounced letter by letter (M.E.Z) or can they be pronounced as a whole word (MEZ) which sounds better and easier to say

I appologize for my english

Comment: Yes, you can make a name out of your initials if you want. You can decide how you would like to be called (as long as you do not do it for illegal purposes!) :)

Comment: I used to have a colleague called Jak Kelly. I don't remember what his given name was - he never used it. J.A.K. were his initials, and that's where his everyday name came from.

Comment: Naming is not really part of standard English, as 'rules', if any, are so arbitrary. You (or others) can and perhaps will decide what you are to be called. I've had three diminutives foisted upon me; the BBC is often called 'the Beeb'; SGP Barton at school was always 'SGP', but A Barton was 'Bandy'. David Aspinall was 'Stilge'. I never _did_ find out what the reason (if any) was. But you can _ask_ people to call you whatever you like; not all of them may play ball. // Look up 'acronym' for 'less arbitrary' (ie now accepted) practices, like 'BBC' vs 'ISA'.

Comment: MEZ is not hard to pronounce.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It depends on how it's being pronounced. For instance, taking US English versus UK English as a broad example, *MEZ* could be pronounced *em-ee-zee* or *em-ee-zed*. But even that could be simplified as *em-eeze*. There's no telling how an individual, looking at the three letters, would actually pronounce it.

Comment: @Jason Bassford i want it to be pronounced like the way you read it as in "mes"merize not letter by letter

Comment: How is this a Question about language?

I knew a man actually named A J Surname. His business associates called him "Ay-Jay" and his family, "Aj…"

I knew another with a name I never understood, who wanted everyone to call him "Maj…" so we all did.

When you want people to call you "wotnot" why not just explain that to them?